# Splitting ListView's rows in Android

Tags: android, listview

Writing Android application, I encountered some difficulty in customizing `ListView`.

I need to have three `TextView`s in a row, first of ones must be aligned to the left, second to the center and the last to the right.

Is it possible to do it through XML only? Or, if not, how to reach that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `layout_weight` attribute in a simple horizontal `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="first"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="second"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="third"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Left"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Right"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```